# List packages that were updated with the new poky version?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have a image recipe that inherits the core image (`inherit core-image`) and ads some additional packages of its own.

I'm doing an update to a new version of poky. Is there a way to see what packages (relevant to my image) have been affected with the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes, in the meaning of: the information is certainly available.

No, as this information is not directly readable for a variety of reasons:
The term "relevant" to my image is highly unspecific. Does it mean that a package needs to be recompiled? Does it mean that a package comes in a new version? Does it mean that something in your image dependendency tree changed? Or does it mean that something in your build-time dependencies changed?

For the recompilation, it will almost certainly apply to every single package. Reason: poky releases usually bring a new gcc version, and this triggers recompilation for basically everything.

Now for the good news:

[MACHINE refers to your specific machine type, IMAGE to the image recipe in question]

Yes for **packages in your image**: in your

```
tmp/deploy/images/MACHINE/IMAGE.manifest
```

is a concise list of packages and their respective version in your image. Just diff the file between before and after the update, and there you go!

Yes for **dependencies**: do a

```
bitbake -g IMAGE
```

before and after the update, keeping the resulting

```
recipes-depends.dot, task-depends.dot
```

files for comparison. Now diffing those will give you precise (albeit probably not well formatted) information what has changed in which way and will affect your image build.